# Quelques exemples d' « alternance codique » dans son français et leurs motivations ?

Tags: linguistique, emprunts, registre, dialectes

> L’**alternance codique** (de l'anglais *code switching*) désigne
> l’alternance entre plusieurs codes linguistiques (langues, dialectes
> ou registres de langue) au sein d’un même et unique discours ou
> énoncé, voire au sein d’une phrase, le plus souvent là où les syntaxes
> des deux codes s'alignent [...]
>
> [ Wikipédia, « [alternance codique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternance_codique) » ]

Quels seraient quelques exemples (2-3) parmi les plus **fréquents** et **courants** dans son/sa sociolecte/région et par quoi seraient-ils [motivés](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternance_codique#Motivations) ou quelle serait leur(s) fonction(s) ?

Ainsi on omettra :

- Des emprunts lexicalisés, a fortiori employés depuis longtemps (comme *week-end* ou *spaghetti*)
- Des termes très techniques peu connus à l'extérieur d'un domaine
- Des mots qui ne seraient pas raisonnablement représentatifs (entre deux personnes etc.)

Comment: En général ou en particulier ?  Des thèses, des tonnes.  Il y a beaucoup de langues (et en quoi consiste la définition ?) dans ta question s'il s'agit-il de code switching entre L1 et L2 ou le registre ou la sociolecte ?  Les langues, tout. Les question tags font souvent partie du code switching par exemple, tu cherches des exemples concrets ?

Comment: Pardon, c'était peut-être pas clair.  Des *question tags* je parle de code switching, pas des étiquettes du site FSE.  You know, tag markers, tu vois pour ton sondage.  Est-ce un sondage ?

Comment: Je suis très étonné que l'article Wikipedia et l'étude qu'il cite ne placent pas l'environnement socio-culturel plus haut dans la liste des facteurs d'alternance codique. Peut-être que c'est dû au fait que beaucoup de mots à forte particularité socio-culturelle dans la langue A n'ont pas d'équivalent exact dans la langue B et ne sont donc pas considérés comme une alternance. Mais au vu des exemples donnés (*entertainment*, *in need*) j'ai un doute.

Comment: @guillaume31 Peut-être voir l'[article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching) en langue anglaise, beaucoup plus vaste ? Je ne connais pas assez le sujet pour pouvoir discuter des raisons qui causent le phénomène... Je ne suis pas attaché à une valeur particulière que l'un ou l'autre article attribuerait à une motivation. C'est davantage pour moi un truc exploratoire et dans l'article en français il y a peu d'exemples en français...